# ASP.NET MVC DDD E-commerce - Admin and front separation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, domain-driven-design, e-commerce

I'm going to write an ASP.NET MVC 2 application using Domain Driven Design. I'm trying to figure out how to separate the Admin from the store front. I could create 2 MVC projects, but regarding the services for them, should they be in separate projects as well or could I use the CatalogManager, for example, for both, Admin and the store front, and mix up all the services?

Currently I have a class library for each part of my domain (services, infrastructure, model, etc.)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm searching for the same argument.
I have to create 2 different domains or the domain model is the same?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out [Areas](http://elegantcode.com/2010/03/13/asp-net-mvc-2-areas/) as a way to separate your application into logical domains

Comment: Yes I'm considering that, but my real concern is about a good way to use my pre-existent domain components without making the application a mess.

Comment: When you say services do you mean WCF service? or a repository in your Models directory?

Comment: My domain services, infrastructure services, etc.